# Should taking the log of a dataset reduce the MAE?

Tags: regression, error, logarithm

I was curious if my assumption is correct that when you take the log of a dataset then run a regression (for example) that my Mean Absolute Error should be less than when I run a regression without taking the log of the dataset. Is it dependent on the distribution of the data set? Or is it always the case that the MAE would be reduced when you take log of a dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to do this? Comparing mean average error between models with different scale for the response do not make much sense.  But yes, answer will depend on the data.